# Why can't I change the value when intercepting HTML form's submit event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am using [jQuery Input Mask Plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) to mask my inputs in the forms, and I need to submit a value without mask to the server.  My approach was to label form with a class '.masked-inputs-form', and then bind to its 'submit' event, replacing relevant inputs' values.  What I find, after tedious debugging, is that the posted values are the ones visible on screen and not the ones set in my function.  Any ideas from community?

JavaScript equivalent of my code is as follows:

```
(function() {
  $(function() {
    return $(".masked-inputs-form").on('submit', function(e) {
      var i, input, inputs, len;
      e.preventDefault();
      inputs = $('.decimal-input-mask, .signed-decimal-input-mask, .integer-input-mask, .signed-integer-input-mask');
      for (i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
        input = inputs[i];
        $(input).val(input.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
      }
      return this.submit();
    });
  });
}).call(this);

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="#" class="masked-inputs-form form-inline" id="my_form" method="post" role="form">
  <input id="hidden_input" type="hidden" value="1">
  <input class="form-control decimal-input-mask" id="positive_integer_input" size="10" type="text" style="text-align: right;">
  <input class="form-control decimal-input-mask" id="percent_input" size="10" type="text" style="text-align: right;">
  <input class="form-control signed-decimal-input-mask" id="plus_minus_input" size="15" type="text" style="text-align: right;">
  <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

UPDATE:  I found a workaround by using an option from the plugin "removeMaskOnSubmit", that originally did not work because I had a old JS version of the plugin.

Comment: Just a hint for the future: have a look at [`.val(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function) :)

Comment: curious why you use `this.submit()` inside the jquery submit handler? Form will submit anyway without calling that. I would prevent the submit and run through the values again to see what they are after the `replace()`. Also see if plugin has a destroy method

Comment: does the mask apply to data assigned programmatically?  You're setting the value back to the input, which gives the masking plugin the ability to mask the data again.

Comment: The plugin has an option [`removeMaskOnSubmit`](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask#removemaskonsubmit). I suggest you use that.

Comment: [`autoUnmask`](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask#autounmask) may also be useful.

Comment: @Barmar, right on!  I have discovered this option as well after posting my question.  What I have not mentioned is that I am coding this in Rails and deferred to getting the mask JS plugin via a GEM.  Guess it was getting the older code base, since the removeMaskOnSubmit option was not working.  Teach me not to fall into the "GEM" trap again...

Comment: @charlietfl, I did not use that at first, but found my form NOT submitting when did not reset default event chain and manually submit the form.  Not sure why, to be honest.

Comment: my bad...you have preventDefault() stopping it. I hadn't noticed that